# how to get localhost URL to online web server

Tags: php

i wanna to access my XML file from local computer to my web server but i try to fetch localhost URL contain XML file to my web server but wont work please help me and that is my code in

```
<?php 
   $url="http://localhost/mzee/employee/reports.xml";
   $ch=curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $data=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $xml=simplexml_load_string($data);
    ?>
```

Comment: google the terms ngrok or local tunnel and check out those, hope you'll able to access then

Comment: @lazaro This is possible but you'll need to use the IP address of your computer. As such, you'll need to change your firewall to allow it and also, bear in mind that without a static IP, it will change. One way around this is to have a *chron job like* script that sends your current IP address to your server. However this all becomes a security hazard. Why not instead periodically upload `reports.xml` to your server via a *chron job like* script on your local computer.